# React Apollo returning Null when Graphiql and Altair succeed with exact same mutation?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I've tested this mutation on my django-graphene GraphiQL endpoint, and tested it through Altair (postman for graphql) at the exact same endpoint that my apollo client is pointed at. I run the same mutation with the same formatting, and it works with GraphiQL and Altair - new database entry.

Through react-apollo, it doesn't produce an error, and my django console prints: `[29/Nov/2017 01:51:08] "POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 75`

Yet nothing actually hits the database. I tried console.log the query, and it prints the data structure, but the object it was supposed to be create just says "null".

I've rebuilt it twice to no avail.  Here's the Altair mutation that works as expected:

```
mutation {
  leadCreate(
    newLead:{
      firstName: "Bob",
      lastName: "Dole",
      email: "BobDole@graphql.com",
      staff: "1"
    }) {
    lead {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns the result in Altair:

```
STATUS: OK  STATUS CODE: 200 TIME SPENT: 641ms

{
 "data": {
  "leadCreate": {
   "lead": {
    "id": "2773"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Same result in GraphiQL.

Here's my Apollo Link setup in my index.js:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I should note that all my queries work properly, so I'm fairly confident that the above is all correct.

Here's my LeadQuickCreate.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Button, Input } from 'antd';
import { USER_ID } from '../../Utilities/constants';

class LeadQuickCreate extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
  };

  createLink = async () => {
    const staff = localStorage.getItem(USER_ID);
    const {
      firstName, lastName, phone, email,
    } = this.state;
    const newLead = await this.props.createQuickLead({
      variables: {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phone,
        email,
        staff,
      },
    });
    console.log('NewLead = ', newLead);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      firstName, lastName, phone, email,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Input
            value={firstName}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Lead's First Name"
          />
          <Input
            value={lastName}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Lead's Last Name"
          />
          <Input
            value={phone}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ phone: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Lead's Phone Number"
          />
          <Input
            value={email}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Lead's email address"
          />
        </div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.createLink()}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CREATE_QUICK_LEAD = gql`
  mutation CreateQuickLead(
    $firstName: String!
    $lastName: String
    $phone: String
    $email: String
    $staff: ID!
  ) {
    leadCreate(
      newLead: {
        firstName: $firstName
        lastName: $lastName
        phone: $phone
        email: $email
        staff: $staff
      }
    ) {
      lead {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(CREATE_QUICK_LEAD, { name: 'createQuickLead' })(LeadQuickCreate);
```

When I click the Submit button, the console log prints this:

```
{data: {…}}
  data:
   leadCreate:
    lead: null 
    __typename: "LeadSerializerMutation"
```

etc.

So I'm stuck. Any ideas on where it's getting lost?

Thank you!

*EDIT: Egads! When closely reviewing the response after sending a 'correct format' form as suggested, I realized that the "staff" const was submitting as a string. Not sure why my backend wasn't throwing a visible error, but a quick "parseInt(staff) before submitting and it works!*

Comment: Have you checked the XHR requests under the network tab in Chrome dev tools? Do you see the request (you should be able to since it's logged server-side), and is it properly formatted (i.e. does the body correspond to what you're sending with GraphiQL or Altair)?

Comment: `{"operationName":"CreateQuickLead","variables":{"firstName":"Test","lastName":"test","phone":"test","email":"test","staff":"1"},"query":"mutation CreateQuickLead($firstName: String!, $lastName: String, $phone: String, $email: String, $staff: ID!) {\n  leadCreate(newLead: {firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, phone: $phone, email: $email, staff: $staff}) {\n    lead {\n      id\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}`

Comment: Nice that you found the issue, you should consider writing your own answer and set it to accepted so that others faced with a similar issue know where to look!

Comment: Done. Thanks @Jaxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally noticed that the `ID!` that was expected was being sent as a string, and the graphene endpoint was looking for an integer. Simply changing my mutation call to this worked:

```
createLead = async values => {
    const { firstName, lastName, phone, email, } = values;
    let staff = localStorage.getItem(USER_ID);
    staff = parseInt(staff);

    const newLead = await this.props.createQuickLead({
      variables: {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phone,
        email,
        staff,
      },
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. Remember to "accept" your own answer as the solution to your question (only you can do this as the creator of the question).